# w2ui toolbar icon and font awesome 5 not rendering

Tags: w2ui

I am seeing an empty box for my grid toolbar icons using font awesome 5 classes.
Usage:

```
...
toolbar: { 
    items : [
        {
            type: 'button', 
            id: 'toobar_download', 
            icon: 'fas fa-download', 
            text: 'Download',
            tooltip: 'Download Report',
            disabled:false,
            onClick: function (event) { 
                that.download();
            }
        }
    ]
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the workaround that allowed the font awesome icons to render properly, adding the oh-so-famous !important

```
.w2ui-tb-image .fa, .fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" !important;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```